# Show checkstyle violations in eclipse problems tab

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, checkstyle

Is it possible to configure the eclipse-cs plugin to show the Checkstyle violations in the "Problems" view as well and not only in the "Checkstyle violations" tab in eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The checkstyle problems should show up by default in the problems tab.

In case they won't appear, have a look if the "Checkstyle Problem" type is selected in the filter settings for the problems tab.

The filter settings can be opened by clicking on the "Filters..." button in the Problems tab:

[image: Filters...]

In the Filters windows you can add the "Checkstyle Problem" type to make sure that these also appear in the problems tab:

[image: FilterSettings]

After adding the checkstyle problem type in the filter settings, the checkstyle violations should appear in the problems tab.